# Counting rows by a condition in another table

Tags: oracle, counting

Need to count the number of rows in one table which connect to a second table by (name.sample) where in the second table the (name.sample) was created before (or after) a certain date.

Comment: Bingo !!  Thank you very much.  What a forum........... No hassles, just answers....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.my_foreign_key_column = t2.my_primary_key_column
where t2.creation_date >= 'my_date_literal'
```

Comment: Bingo !! Thank you very much. What a forum........... No hassles, just answers....